# Django app or middleware for modern brower detection

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a Django site that uses Bootstrap from Twitter.  I've tested the site on the latest versions of Chrome, FireFox and Safari.  It looks really nice.  And then we have Internet Explorer (play failure music... wonk, wonk, woooonk).  It seems to work ok, but it doesn't look near as nice (e.g. no rounded corners, etc).  What I would like is to detect IE and then redirect them to a page that tells them that IE users may experience issues and that it is strongly recommended to use a more-compliant browser.  But, unfortunately, I can't force them to not use IE.  So, I need to add a flag saying that they've been show the page.  Does anyone know of an app/middleware for doing something like this?  I've done some googling, but really haven't found anything.

I don't think it would be terribly hard to write, but I would rather not re-invent the wheel.

Version information:  Django 1.3.1; Bootstrap 2.0.2 and jQuery 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing at http://djangosnippets.org that does this (and I doubt there is, TBH), write it - because like you say, it's not hard - and contribute it